# Solve Diffusion Equation with Neumann Boundary Conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Let $u_t = u_{xx} + f(x,t), x\in (0,1), t \in (0,T).$

Let $u(x,0) = g(x), u_x(0,t) = h_0(t), $ and $u_x(1,t) = h_1(t)$.

Find $f,g,h_0, $ and $ h_1$ such that $u(x,t) = e^{-(x-1/2)^2}e^{-t}$ is an exact solution.

I understand the general way to solve the diffusion equation, by choosing some $u(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$, but this seems to be much more complicated with the addition of the $f(x,t)$ term. Any help on getting started would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are complicating the problem for yourself.  You know that the solution is $u(x,t) = e^{-(x-1/2)^2}e^{-t}$. So, plug the known expression for $u$ into the PDE and solve for $f$:

$f(x,t) = u_t - u_{xx} = e^{-(x-1/2)^2}e^{-t}(-4x^2+4x)$.

Likewise, you can compute $g$ by plugging in $t=0$ into the expression for $u$:

$g(x) = u(x,0) = e^{-(x-1/2)^2}e^{-0} = e^{-(x-1/2)^2}$.

Follow similar calculations for $h_0$ and $h_1$.